# how can i ignore symbols in a line of VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to create several variables in VB which will be strings which will hold various snippets of HTML code.

The issue i am having, is that it picks up all of the symbols and function words. i just want a piece of code (for example:   `<div class="event-container">`   ) to be declared as a string.

Thank you

Shaun

Comment: Unclear. Could you edit and paste some sample code showing how you declare and use those variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes inside a string will make the string unparsable (where does it start and end?)

Use single quotes which are ok for HTML:

```
 str = "<div class='event-container'>"
```

Or use `""` to escape a single `"`

```
 str = "<div class=""event-container"">"
```

Comment: Thanks very much Alex!

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim mystring as String = "<div class=""event-container"">"
```

Every `"` needs to be escaped